# Reusing Custom UITableViewCell in multiple classes

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I created a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.  In one viewController, it works fine.  In another, the labels appear as the default, (e.g. @"Label"), but do not have the text that I want in them.  It is as if the outlets are not connected.  However, in one class, it works fine and I see the labels change accordingly.

In both ViewControllers, in viewdidLoad, I do:

```
[self.baseTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TargetDetailTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:TargetCellIdentifier];
```

In both .m files of the ViewController, above the methods, I have:

```
static NSString *TargetCellIdentifier = @"TargetDetailTableViewCellIdentifier";
```

Note, I tried changing this string identifier between the two classes to see if that was causing the problem and it was not.

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I do the same thing for both to get my cell:

```
TargetDetailTableViewCell *cell = (TargetDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TargetCellIdentifier];
```

Then I do the same in both and do something like:

```
cell.descriptionLabel = @"test";
```

In one viewController, the descriptionLabel changes, in the other, it does not.  So I then tried to change the TargetDetailTableViewCell to a standard UITableViewCell and my values are getting passed to that UITableViewCell object correctly.  I see that it's cell.textLabel.text does get assigned, whereas in my second viewController where I try to reuse this UITableViewCell, it does not work.

Is there something I'm missing with reusing a UITableViewCell between different UITableViews in different UIViewControllers?  Thanks.